# Writing UNC path names to a different drive?

Tags: filesystems, mappeddrive, unc

To write a link to a file on another server I write

```
\\ServerName\FilePathName
```

which maps to

```
\\ServerName C:\FilePathName
```

How can I write the link to access a different drive, e.g. W:\?

I want the link to access

```
\\ServerName W:\FilePathName
```

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like a mix up of different principles.

- A machine named `ServerName` is sharing a path
  `c:\path\to\sharename` which is shared via name `sharename`. In this
  scenario, you connect to the share name remotely simply with 
  `\\ServerName\sharename` - not the whole path of the share name.
- By default, administrators are also able to access the root of each drive and the whole contents thereof, by navigating to `\\ServerName\[driveletter]$` so for example, `\\ServerName\d$` - but again, by default this is administrator-only - and I highly recommend leaving it this way.

As for the question of accessing a share present from a different drive on the machine `ServerName`, you would simply make sure that the content on that machine is properly set to share and access it via the above naming scheme as normal, eg `\\ServerName\shareOnOtherDrive`